# Return from activity to last visited intent

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a main activity that exists out of three fragments. Fragment 2 is the main fragment. On fragment 3 I have a button. Once I click the button it directs the user to a `ChatActivity`. The `ChatActivity` has an `onBackButtonPressed` that should return the user back to fragment 3. However, it seems that it would always return the user to fragment 2 (the main fragment).

How can I bring the user to the fragment they last visited, or at least back to fragment 3?

Edit:

I added this block of code in the button `onClick` function:

```
ChatFragment fragment = new ChatFragment();
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.main_tabPager, fragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

When I click the back button in the activity it does not return me to fragment 3 but instead rebuild the fragmentpager and start back at Fragment 2.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally `addToBackStack()` on fragment transaction should be enough as per documentation, but it seems not true at times, so we have to handle the popping up of the back stack upon Back button pressed by ourselves. I added this to my activity and it worked as expected:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0 ){
      getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
  } else {
      super.onBackPressed();
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I editted my question. Hope you can help me

Comment: I am going to try this, I will keep you posted

Answer (score 0):

When you are opening fragment 3 from main fragment (fragment 2), add fragment 3 into backstack like this:

```
Fragment3 fragment3 = new Fragment3();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.content, fragment3).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

You should add all fragments to backstack that you want to return to

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think I almost got it. What should I put in the add section? R.id.[fragment2.view]? Or R.id.[fragment3.view]?

Comment: in add method first parameter is the id of framelayout (layout) where you want fragment to be loaded.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I editted my question. Hope you can help me

Comment: Are you using tabs or viewpager in your activity that include fragment 1, 2 and 3  or are you just opening fragments on top of each other?